# Move cursor to opposite side of selection in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to move the cursor to the other side of the selected text in vscode? Like here I want to add expand my selection to include 'eiusmod' on the left, but I don't know of any shortcut or command or extension that allows it.

[image: screenshot of cursor on text]

Answer (score 2):

The extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) has a command `selectby.swapActive`

Bind it to a key of your choice or call it from the Command Palette: **Swap the achor and active (cursor) position of the selection(s)**.